# Speeding up WMI query to select a single remote printer

Tags: powershell, printing, wmi

We have a print server containing ~800 printers and I'm looking for a speedy way to select just one of the printer objects in powershell v3.

Here are the ways I've tried:

```
$printer = Get-Wmiobject win32_printer -computername $server | where {$_.name -Match $printer}
$printer = Get-Wmiobject win32_printer -computername $server -filter "name='$printer'"
$printer = Get-Wmiobject win32_printer -computername $server -filter "name='$printer'" -property name
$printer = Get-Wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM win32_printer WHERE name = '$printer'" -computername $server
```

All 4 of those methods take ~25 seconds. Is there any way I can simply select the remote printer quickly?

Comment: Highly unlikely I'm afraid. Though WMI is extremely powerful, it just isn't that fast.

Comment: Are you running PS V4? If it's the case you could compare with the cmdlet `Get-Printer`

Comment: I'm stuck with V3 unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WMI object being returned will have a Path property.  You can use that to construct a WMI object that will go directly to the printer once you know the path:

```
[WMI]'\\Server1\root\cimv2:Win32_Printer.DeviceID="Printer1"'
```

You may want to build that into a function that contains a hash table of known printer names and the WMI path to each one, or you can construct the string if you know the exact server and printer name.

That should return results almost immediately.

Comment: This works for me. Takes 2 seconds to grab a printer using this method. Thanks!

Comment: on a large print server this method is 100 times faster !